# Tkinter Canvas: Change option without changing others OR set all options again

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Creating a fairly basic window and trying to keep everything nice and tightly jammed in the window so that there are no gaps between items in the `grid` requires setting the `canvas`'s border to -2 (annoying, should be 0, but a different complaint for a different day). However, when updating other attributes (in this case `bg`), that `bd` attribute gets reset irreparably. Requesting that property returns the -2 it got set to, but the `canvas` acts like it isn't (i.e., the `canvas` appears to have a `bd` value of 0, despite saying it has -2 when asked).

**How can one update only one attribute without breaking the `bd` attribute?**

OR,

**How can one set all the attributes for that object simultaneously after it already exists similarly to when it was created so that `bd` actually takes effect?**

A simple example that lets you play with it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

class MyGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.buttonx = tk.Button(master, text='goblue', command=partial(self.gocol, 'lightblue'), bg='lightblue')
        self.buttonx.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.buttony = tk.Button(master, text='gogrey', command=partial(self.gocol, 'grey'), bg='grey')
        self.buttony.grid(row=2,column=0)

        self.canvasx_specs = {
                'width' : 400, 
                'height' : 400, 
                'bg' : 'grey', 
                'bd' : -2
            }
        self.canvasx = tk.Canvas(master, **self.canvasx_specs)
        self.canvasx.grid(rowspan=9,row=1,column=1)

    def gocol(self, col):
        ## Method 1
        self.canvasx['bg']=col
        # self.canvasx.configure(bg=col)

        ## Method 2
        # self.canvasx_specs['bg'] = col
        # self.canvasx.configureall(**self.canvasx_specs)

top = tk.Tk()
mywin = MyGUI(top)
top.mainloop()
```

It doesn't appear to matter if you set `bd` to -2 again, it still acts like it is 0. It also doesn't appear to matter if you use members access or `configure` function (see Method 1 above), it has the same effect.

I don't want to delete the whole canvas, it may have drawn objects in it already, and I don't want to redraw everything when the background (or some other option) changes.

Comment: on my computer `'bg': -2` doesn't work even on start. But `'highlightthickness': 0` resolves problem.

Comment: BTW: this is not tag but property. Doc for [Canvas](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.config-method) uses name "option"

Comment: @furas, Updated title and question, thank you. And the code above runs on my Windows 10 in Python3 without errors/warnings.

Comment: @furas Indeed, highlightthickness does resolve the problem on my machine. Please post as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Canvas` (and other widgets) may have two elements - `border` and `highlight`.

If you set `bd` to 0 or -2 then you can still see `highlight` which you can remove with `'highlightthickness': 0`